# Leaflet и колесо мышки: шаг Zoom'а

Tags: leafletjs

Есть карта, сделанная ни библиотеке `Leaflet.js`
Колесо мыши по дэфолту приближает или отдаляет на 2 зума.
Как называется метод в этой библиотеке, что бы исправить `2` на `1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

почему-то шаг х2 зума присутствует именно в **Гугл Хроме**. в **IE** шаг х1.
чтобы это пофиксить надо залезть в `leaflet.js` и найти `wheelDelta/120` и изменять значение **120** на нужное
увеличение этого значения уменьшит шаг зума, а уменьшение - наоборот увеличит